# How can I link a category to a newly created CMS page

Tags: magento2, category, magento-2.0, cms, navigation

I created a CMS page and I would like to link the page to one of the categories on my nav. How can I do this?

Comment: https://github.com/Mestrona/Mestrona_CategoryRedirect This will be ur solution

Comment: Any other way that doesn't involve extensions or plugins?

Comment: HI @DevAnd. This is the Best Way/ If you find better than this please share. Thanks

Comment: Can you give me some instructions on how to implement this. Thanks so much!